# Grafana multi dimension time series graph and filter by any field

Tags: graph, time-series, grafana, dashboard

in grafana, can I create a time series graph, data contains  "salary, sex, age range", the graph should allow me select a sex value or age range value, for example, if I select male, it should display average salary grouped by age range for all male. If I select an age range 20-30, it should display average salary grouped by sex.

Is it possible in a single panel?

Comment: It is possible, but it depends heavily on what datasource is used, how you expect specify range and so on. Consider adding this information.

Comment: Also, what output do you expect if nothing is selected?

Answer (score 0):

You could do two separate queries. Create two template variables, one for "sex" and another for "age range."

```
SELECT mean("salary") AS "average_salary" FROM "your_measurement" WHERE "sex" = $sex_variable GROUP BY time($__interval), "age_range"
```

```
SELECT mean("salary") AS "average_salary" FROM "your_measurement" WHERE "age_range" = $age_range_variable GROUP BY time($__interval), "sex"
```

Create a graph panel, in the "Queries" tab of the panel settings, add both queries and set the visualization options for each query. Add the template variables to your dashboard.